# Number of Abelian Cubic Number Fields of given Discriminant

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

According to Cohn's paper on "the density of Abelian cubic fields", there are exactly $2^v$ Abelian cubic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ with discriminant $f^2$, where $v\ge0$ and $f$ is of the form $f=9p_1\cdots p_v$ or $f=p_0p_1\cdots p_v$ with $p_i$ being primes congruent to $1$ (mod $3$). I know the splitting field of an irreducible cubic polynomial is Abelian if and only if its discriminant is a square, but how can we deduce that it must be a product of primes as above and the exact number of extensions for every such $f$?

Comment: You mean whose discriminant divides $f^2$. Do you know Kronecker Weber, the simplest case of class field theory ? It says the abelian cubic field is a subfield of a cyclotomic field. The cyclotomic Galois group and Artin map and discriminant are known. Conversely to any such cyclotomic field, if $3| \phi(n)$ then it contains some cubic abelian extensions. It remains to list them and find their discriminant